# Is possible to share a text variable across documents of a book in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6

I have a text variable for paragraph style A. The book is like this: `ch1_00`, `ch1_01`, `ch1_02`.

`ch1_00` contains the chapter cover, and I want to put here the text variable based on the words contained in the `ch1_00` document.

All those documents are contained in a book. So I would like to get the variable to work in the `ch1_01`, `ch1_02` too. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of.

It can't be fully automatic, but you can set the text variable in the master document in the book palette as a `Custom Text` Text Variable by copy-pasting it from the paragraph in question.

Then use the `Sync` command and set it for `Text Variables` only which will update all instances of it in the balance of the book.

Answer (score 0):

I also require this functionality but can confirm Will's answer that there does not seem to be  any automated solution.

I reference 3 paragraph styles from the front cover of reports as separate Running Headers in order to automatically populate a pre-styled 'Footer' master page.

This works fine if the text being referenced is NOT in a master page itself, plus this does NOT synchronise across books.